# Connecting the envelope indicator in panel to my GMail account in 13.10

Tags: 13.10, indicator, mail, gmail

Is there a way of connecting the envelope in the upper panel in Ubuntu 13.10, to notify me when i get mail on Gmail? I mean this little thing:

[image]

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu web apps enabled? I thought that gmail webapp should do this automatically (when you have gmail open in your browser).

Comment: I had it, but it didn't work. + i don't need the indicator when i have it already open in my browser :)

Comment: I don't think there is an easier way to have a gmail indicator. Without using another email program. You will have to have gmail in your browser minimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Unity Mail](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-mail) [image: Install unity-mail]

There is a useful application **unity-mail** designed for use with a GMail account but also suitable for other accounts.

After installation it will make use of the mail indicator in the top panel. The indicator will turn blue on unread mails, and the mail subject will be listed on dropdown. Clicking on the Unity Mail entry will open GMail in your browser.

[image]

In addition you can have a Launcher icon which displays the count of unread mails, and will also give easy access to GMail inbox, composer, or application settings, and more.

[image]

On the settings menu you can define the interval Unity Mail checks for new mails, as well as various notification on receiving mails:

[image]

Unity Mail can manage several different accounts.

For newer releases (>= 15.10) Unity-Mail can be installed from the official ppa:

**ppa:robert-tari/main**